# Add cron to Crontab

Tags: cron

I am looking at these tutorials https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-cron-to-automate-tasks-on-a-vps

and I have cron installed but when I write the command `5 * * * * curl http://www.google.com` i get the error:

```
-bash: 5: command not found
```

How do I add a cron?

Comment: Usually first by running `crontab -e` to edit the crontab file for the user in question.

Comment: @thrig so if I am adding it as root, do I run it all in one line or 2 separate lines?

Comment: `crontab -e` should fire up your `EDITOR` and then the crontab entry should be just that one line, then save and quit the editor. There's also often files under `/etc` where `root` cron jobs can also go.

Answer (score 3):

In the [document you cited](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-cron-to-automate-tasks-on-a-vps) you need to keep reading until you get to the section entitled **Configuration**. This tells you how to configure your `crontab`.

Answer (score 3):

`5 * * * * curl http://www.google.com` is not a shell command, it's an entry in the [crontab file](http://linux.die.net/man/5/crontab). The crontab file is a text file that contains the description of jobs, with the time specification (here `5 * * * *`, meaning every hour at 5 minutes past the hour) followed by the command to execute (here `curl http://www.google.com`). You need to edit the crontab file to add this line (in [that tutorial you were reading](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-cron-to-automate-tasks-on-a-vps), keep reading until the section “Configuration”). You do this with the [`crontab` command](http://linux.die.net/man/1/crontab). Run the command

```
crontab -e
```

This brings up the crontab file in an editor. Add the line, then save and exit.

Note that on some systems, the default editor is vi, which is difficult to use if you know nothing about it. If you don't know vi, make sure that the default editor is one that you're comfortable with. To change the editor, set the `VISUAL` environment variable, e.g.

```
export VISUAL=nano
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is trying to say that curl cannot be found as it is not in PATH. Either use an absolute path, or set PATH in the crontab file.

Comment: The error message is `5: command not found`, not `curl: command not found`.

Comment: Correct, I misread it. Didn't pay attention to that 5. Sorry.